# Как изменить размер CardView с анимацией?

Tags: android, android-sdk, material-design, android-ui

У меня есть layout в котором есть `CardView` внутри которого лежит, скажем, картинка.

Я хочу увеличить высоту и ширину этой CardView вместе с анимацией так как это делают в [Material Design Guidelines](https://material-design.storage.googleapis.com/publish/material_v_4/material_ext_publish/0B6Okdz75tqQsZWtfWjlEQ0RTcXc/whatismaterial-materialprop-transformingmaterial-PaperShapeLinear_xhdpi_005.webm)

Я пробовал 2 способа:

1. `cardView.animate().scaleX().scaleY()` - этот способ изменяет размер `CardView` но вместе с ним и изменяется размер всего, что внутри его даже если у содержимого выставлена специфичная ширина и высота;
2. можно сделать `cardView.getLayoutParams()` и потом изменить height и width или можно добавить margin - это действительно меняет размер, но непонятно как это анимировать.

Весьма странно, но я не нашел никаких стоящих рецептов в гугле.

Comment: Вот так пробовали? https://gist.github.com/rafali/5146957

Comment: Вот это ещё, кажется, может помочь: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28795348/3212712

Comment: @ЮрийСПб первый способ подошел, но я думал если решения из коробки вместо запиливания своего Animator. Второй способ не работает.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться вот [этим](https://gist.github.com/rafali/5146957) способом с gitHub-а:

Создаём анимацию изменения параметров View:

```
public class ResizeAnimation extends Animation {
    final int startWidth;
    final int targetWidth;
    View view;

    public ResizeAnimation(View view, int targetWidth) {
        this.view = view;
        this.targetWidth = targetWidth;
        startWidth = view.getWidth();
    }

    @Override
    protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
        int newWidth = (int) (startWidth + (targetWidth - startWidth) * interpolatedTime);
        view.getLayoutParams().width = newWidth;
        view.requestLayout();
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(int width, int height, int parentWidth, int parentHeight) {
        super.initialize(width, height, parentWidth, parentHeight);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean willChangeBounds() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Применяем её:

```
ResizeAnimation resizeAnimation = new ResizeAnimation(view, targetSize);
resizeAnimation.setDuration(600);
view.startAnimation(resizeAnimation);
```